# Сортировка в QTableView

Tags: c++, qt

При установке `setSortingEnabled(true)` экземпляра `QTableView` в хэдерах колонок появляются переключаемые значки сортировки, но при нажатиях на них сама сортировка данных в таблице не происходит. Я так понимаю, установки одной `setSortingEnabled(true)` мало? Нужно переопределить ещё что-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нужно переопределить ещё что-то?

Безусловно. Там где-то в дебрях вашего кода опишите нужный слот, который будет сортировать (или обеспечивать условия сортировки), назовем его `virtual void SlotSort(int iColumn)`. Тогда в виджете, где находится `QTableView` соединяем сигнал со слотом:

```
connect(Table->horizontalHeader(),SIGNAL(sectionClicked(int)), this, SLOT(SlotSort(int)));
```

Где, `Table` - и есть `QTableView*`

**Упрощенный пример слота сортировки**

```
void Browse_Card::SlotSort(int iColumn) {
  // в классе запоминаеися номер колонки текущей сортировки
  SortColumn = iColumn; 
  // в классе запоминаеися направление сортировки
  SortOrder = Table->horizontalHeader()->sortIndicatorOrder();
  // далее собирается "хвост" SQL-запроса, который также хранится в классе
  OrderBy = " ORDER BY ";
  if (Mode == bcService) {
    switch (iColumn) {
      case 3: OrderBy += "LOWER(f.\"Surname\") "; break;
      case 4: OrderBy += "LOWER(f.\"FirstName\") "; break;
      case 5: OrderBy += "LOWER(f.\"Patronymic\") "; break;
      case 6: OrderBy += "f.\"Age\" "; break;
      case 7: OrderBy += "LOWER(f.\"Reason\") "; break;
      case 8: OrderBy += "LOWER(f.\"Present\") "; break;
      default: OrderBy += "f.\"SortNum\" "; break;
    }
  }
  if (SortOrder == Qt::DescendingOrder) OrderBy += "DESC";
  // тут можно флаг выставить, либо emit сигнала на обновление
  NeedUpdate = true;
}
```

Comment: Смысл понятен. Спасибо. Ну а если мне не нужно сортировать данные в модели? Мне достаточно отсортировать их во вьюшечке.

Comment: Тогда нужно использовать `QSortFilterProxyModel` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html)

Comment: А вот это помогло. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Незашта) "Птичку" на вопрос поставьте, что-бы он отображался как "решенный", народу вдруг будет полезно.